# Does broadcast address work over internet?

Tags: networking, linux-networking

I have a subnet /24 (256 public IP addresses). Currently, I assign IP .255 to an LXD container (ubuntu) and it seems working normally. I wonder if someone sends a UDP message to the host that has IP .255 over the internet, will that message get broadcasted to all of my other IP?

Comment: Why do you assign the broadcast IP in the first place? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: This post is a little confusing. I assume this host with .255 isn't part of your public IP range? And I find it very hard to believe your public IP is a /24. In answer to your question though, almost certainly not.

Comment: What do you mean by "class C"? Classes are a historical artifact and were eliminated in the early 1990s. We do not refer to them anymore as if they were actually in use.

Comment: Network classes are dead (please let them rest in peace), killed in 1993 (two years before the commercial Internet!) by RFCs 1517, 1518, and 1519, which defined CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing).

Comment: @dk1111 Who called it "class C"?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider my company is a 3rd party running services for businesses, each client has a dedicated IP so in terms of optimizing profit, I want to try using the broadcast IP, and so far it seems fine.

Comment: @dk1111, if the network is a `/24` network, then using the `.255` address will actually interrupt every host on the network to get to the one host with that address. Many people call any `/24` network a Class C network, but that is most often incorrect. For example, `10.11.12.0/24` is often called a Class C network, but it is clearly a Class  subnet because the first bit of the address starts with `0`. See the very last section of [this two-part](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) answer to learn about the deprecated network classes.

Comment: @MichaelHampton sorry, I just checked, they officially call it "additional subnet /24" but the tech support from my IP provider keeps telling it "class C" so I was wrong. Thanks for your correction.

Comment: edited the question to avoid confusion

Comment: @RonMaupin thanks, luckily there's no communication between containers. Currently, I want to find out any potential danger if I use that broadcast address.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to understand some things.

First, a host only knows about the Limited Broadcast address (`255.255.255.255`), and its own network broadcast address (the last address in the network as defined by the network mask configured on the host). Packets sent to either of those addresses will not travel beyond the network on which they are sent.

For any addresses outside the network of the host, the host has no idea if the address is a host, network, or broadcast address. The host only knows it is an IPv4 address (IPv6 does not have broadcast). For example, a destination `/23` (or smaller) network will have valid `.0` and `.255` host addresses.

The final router in the path is directly connected to the destination network and will know the destination network mask, so it will determine if the destination address is a broadcast or network address. By default, such a router will drop packets sent to the network or broadcast address of a directly connected network. The router could be configured to allow a broadcast destination (directed broadcast), but that would be foolish because it facilitates DoS attacks on the network (broadcasts interrupt every host on a network, and are considered wasteful and obsolete, which is why they were eliminated in IPv6).

Comment: thanks. For short, the broadcast address only works if I send a packet from a host inside that network, correct?

Comment: That is the default. As I explained, a router can be configured to allow a directed broadcast, but that would not be a good idea if it can be reached from the public Internet because you open yourself to a world of hurt.

Answer (score 3):

The notion of .255 as an IPv4 broadcast address exists only within the /24 net it belongs to. The global Internet does not know or care whether that address happens to be the broadcast address of the destination network. Therefore an IP packet sent to that address will be routed normally until it reaches the router responsible for final delivery to that address range, ie. which is either directly connected to the L2 network carrying the /24 net or which has a NAT rule transforming it to a different destination address.

What happens next depends on the configuration on that router.

- If the destination router is directly connected to an Ethernet segment carrying the /24 IPv4 net in question and configured to forward directed broadcasts to it, and does not do NAT then yes, the packet will be broadcasted to all hosts on that segment. (Note that it will *not* be broadcasted to all IP addresses, as your question seems to imply. It will be sent to the broadcast MAC address, but with its original .255 destination IP address. This will cause all network interfaces on the segment to receive it, but each receiving host will see that it is addressed to the broadcast IP address, not to its unicast address, and be free to ignore it for that reason.)
- In most cases however the destination router will be configured to drop packets to the directed broadcast address. This is the default since [RFC2644](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2644).
- Often public IPv4 addresses are transformed into private ones before delivery via NAT. In that case, the .255 address is treated no differently from any other. It is looked up in the NAT table and replaced by whatever actual destination address was found there. No broadcast happens. So the .255 address is not considered a broadcast address in that case.

Those are the most frequent cases. Others are possible but can be solved along the same lines.

Comment: "_If it is a regular router without NAT or packet filtering, and directly connected to an Ethernet segment carrying the /24 IPv4 net in question then yes, the packet will be broadcasted to all hosts on that segment._" No, that was changed in 1999 by _[RFC 2644, Changing the Default for Directed Broadcasts in Routers](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2644)_. Prior to that, yes, a router was obligated by RFC to do just that, but the RFC changed the default behavior of routers so that the packets must be dropped unless the router is specifically configured to allow it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I have corrected the paragraph accordingly.